# Errors during installation brain.js

Tags: npm, npm-install, brain.js

I have had a problem with the brain.js installation for a few days. I don't know if linux on chromebooks doesn't have all the things installed, or if I need to install something 
I type: `npm i brain.js`
output:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/rudzix66/AI/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh /tmp/install-36c7d555.sh
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.7 found at "/usr/local/bin/python3"
npm ERR! (node:2816) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/rudzix66/AI/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/rudzix66/AI/node_modules/gl/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/rudzix66/AI/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/rudzix66/.cache/node-gyp/16.17.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/rudzix66/.cache/node-gyp/16.17.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/rudzix66/AI/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/rudzix66/.cache/node-gyp/16.17.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/rudzix66/AI/node_modules/gl',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: python: not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'python commit_id.py check ..' returned exit status 127 while in angle/src/angle.gyp. while loading dependencies of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/rudzix66/AI/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.136-19393-g8d1faf8b57d7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/rudzix66/AI/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/rudzix66/AI/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

I use Linux on Chromebook

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save brain.js@1.4.10
```